# Connect URLs for request.post using Python

Tags: xml, python-requests

I have two URL's(primary and secondary), I'm trying to connect primary URL with 2 retries if it fails then it has to try connect with secondary URL with again 2
    retries. But unfortunately, it is connecting with only one URL and throwing an exception. Is it possible to connect secondary if the primary URL fails?
    can anyone please help me in resolving this?

```
code:

import os
import requests
import logging

retry_count = 2
timeout = 10

class consumer():
    def send_request(self, retry=retry_count, **kwargs):
        primaryURL = 'www.w3schools.com/xml/'  #sample link
        secondaryURL = 'http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL'  #sample link
        for i in range(retry):
            headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
            try:
                headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
                if primaryURL:
                    response = requests.post(primaryURL, data=body, headers=headers, **kwargs)
                elif secondaryURL:
                    response = requests.post(secondaryURL, data=body, headers=headers)
                break
            except TimeoutError as e:
                print("request post time out for URL")
                continue
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(e)


    def main(self):
        self.send_request()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    consumer = consumer()
    consumer.main()
```

Comment: if primaryURL: is always true (primaryURL is a constant, non-empty string). hence the code will never try the secondary url....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way to do this would be to loop over an list of urls ordered by descending priority. for each url, try to obtain a response n times (based on your retry count). as soon as a response was received, return it and in doing so abort the loop. e.g.:

```
import requests
import logging

retry_count = 2
timeout = 10

class consumer():
    def send_request(self, retry=retry_count, **kwargs):
        for url in ["http://www.w3schoolsss.com/xml/", "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL"]:
            for i in range(retry):
                try:
                    print("trying %s (n = %s)" % (url, i))
                    response = requests.post(url, headers={'content-type': 'text/xml'}, **kwargs)
                    return response
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(e)

    def main(self):
        self.send_request()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    consumer = consumer()
    consumer.main()
```